x509certificate2.GetRSAPublicKey() is failing to verify signature
I am signing data with the private key using x509certificate2.getRSAPrivateKey() and attempting to verify that signature later with public key by using x509certificate2.getRSAPublicKey(). The issue is when verifying with public key it fails.
I have tried signing/verifying sign using both RSA.SignData()/RSA.VerifyData() and RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter.CreateSignature()/RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter.VerifySignature() but both face the same issue.
The verifying works if I do one of two things:

If I sign and verify using private key it works
If I export the parameters from private key and import them into public key i.e.

using RSA privateKey = cert.GetRSAPrivateKey();
using RSA publicKey = cert.GetRSAPublicKey();
publicKey.ImportParameters(privateKey.ExportParameters(false));

I can't do either methods because I sometimes wont have the private key
I have searched all morning and couldn't find anything to get around this.

You need to provide the code that isn't working, together with the data to demonstrate the failure. The code should include the code that generates the signature and the code that attempts to verify the signature, as a [mre], formatted in a [code block].

When verifying with the private key, the public key is extracted under the hood and verified with it. The first case therefore corresponds functionally to the second case, in which you explicitly export the public data from the private key. So it seems to me that the public key cert.GetRSAPublicKey() is not the one associated with the private key cert.GetRSAPrivateKey(). How was the X509certificate2 instance created?

@Topaco ah, thanks a bunch. If you want to drop this below I can accept it as an answer. I don't know why or how it happened but it seems during my testing of creating certificates differently (some using openssl, others in c#) aswell as importing them differently I mustve ended up with faulty certificate. Changed the certificate and it works fine.... shouldve done that much earlier.
